# Is it possible to run a Jetty server with a single connector using two ports, one that uses mutual authentication and another that does not?

Tags: jetty, mutual-authentication

I am trying to design a Jetty instance that accepts incoming requests in two forms:
1. Mutual authentication
2. Non-mutual authentication

Is this possible to do using a single connector with two ports?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, a `ServerConnector` is bound to 1 and only 1 port.

If you need 2 separate ports, then you'll need 2 separate `ServerConnector` configurations.

And based on your question, you'll need different `SslContextFactory` configurations for each connector.